# Convert nested object to JSON Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have dictionary which is nested as shown below:

[image]

I want to convert this object to JSON which will be used to send to controller. I have tried to convert the same to array but nothing worked for me.

```
array = Object.keys(dicCoachList).map(function (k) {
    return dicCoachList[k];
});
```

Which I send to controller using ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Dispatch/SavePatientCoaching/',
        data: { careProfessional : array },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {

        },
```

In controller like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SavePatientCoaching(string[] careProfessional)
{
}
```

If I convert my object to json it just return `"{"1":[],"2":[]}"` So I used array. Please help me send this data to controller.

Comment: To turn an object into JSON, use `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: I already tried that as well `var careProfessional = JSON.stringify(dicCoachList);` which returns `"{"1":[],"2":[]}"`

Comment: Your Action is expecting an array of strings (eg. `['foo', 'bar']`) yet you're sending a dictionary of key/value pairs. One of them needs to be changed to the correct format. Also note that once you've fixed that you don't need to wrap the values in an object when sending from `$.ajax`; just `data: array` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary dicCoachList is not valid for converting to a JSON, you must use an object instead of an array for (CouchId etc).

**Example of correct output format:**

```js
let dicCoachList = {
    data:[
      {CouchId:"test1", CareTeamId:"test1"},
      {CouchId:"test2", CareTeamId:"test2"},
      {CouchId:"test3", CareTeamId:"test3"}
    ]
};
      
console.log( JSON.stringify(dicCoachList));
```